# Assigning values to the datagridview cell

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, variable-assignment

How can I assign values of the textbox to the datagridview cell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
myGridView[col,row].Value = myTextBox.Text;
```

(or have I misunderstood something?)